# Having issues implementing recursion in my attempt at a quick sort algorithm in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I am trying to write my own quick sort algorithm in Python without looking up how it's done professionally (I will learn more this way). If my idea of how I intend to implement this quick sort seems silly to you, (I am aware that it probably will) please don't give me a completely different way of doing it, unless my method will never succeed or at least not without ridiculous measures, please help me reach a solution with my desired method :)

Currently I have a defined a function "pivot" which will take the input list and output three lists, a list of numbers smaller than the pivot (chosen in this case to be the first number in the list every time), a list of numbers equal to the pivot and a list of numbers greater than the pivot.

My next step was to define a function "q_sort". First this function creates a list called "finalList" and fills it with 0s such that it is the same length as the list being sorted. Next it pivots the list and adds the the numbers equal to the pivot to finalList in what is already their correct position (as there are 0s in place to represent the number of items smaller than it and 0s as place-holders again in place of the items bigger than pivot)

This all works fine.

What doesn't work fine is the next step. I have written what I want to happen next in some poorly thought out psuedo-code below:

```
numList = [3, 5, 3, 1, 12, 65, 2, 11, 32]

def pivot(aList):
    biggerNum =[]
    smallerNum = []
    equalNum = [aList[0]]
    for x in range(1, len(aList)):
        if aList[0]<aList[x]:
            biggerNum.append(aList[x])
        elif aList[0]>aList[x]:
            smallerNum.append(aList[x])
        elif aList[0] == aList[x]:
            equalNum.append(aList[x])
    pivoted = [smallerNum, equalNum, biggerNum]
    return pivoted

def q_sort(aList):
    finalList = []
    for x in range(len(aList)):
        finalList.append(0)
    pivot(aList)
    for i in range(len(pivot(aList)[1])):
        finalList[len(pivot(aList)[0])+i] = pivot(aList)[1][i]
```

Pseudo Code:

```
    #if len(smallerNum) != 0:
        #q_sort(smallerNum) <--- I want this to add it's pivot to finalList
    #if len(biggerNum) != 0:
        #q_sort(biggerNum) <--- Again I want this to add it's pivot to finalList
#return finalList <--- Now after all the recursion every number has been pivoted and added
```

What I intend to happen is that if the list of numbers smaller than the pivot actually has any items in it, it will then q_sort this list. This means it will find a new pivot and add it's value to the right position in finalList. The way I imagine it working is that the function only reaches "return finalList" once every number from "numList" has been put in it's correct position. As the recursive nature of including q_sort within q_sort means after pivoting "smallerNum" (and adding the pivot to finalList) it will have another list to pivot.

Comment: The recursive calls should send start/end index. This implantation can't work!

Comment: Is there an implementation that is similar that you might be able to suggest I head towards? Something with the same theory but using a method that actually works?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're starting over on each call: using the entire list, working from both ends.  You need to recur on each partition of the list: the part below the pivot, then the part above the pivot.  This is generally done by passing the endpoints of the sub-list, such as ...

```
def q_sort(aList, low, high):
    if low >= high:
        return

    # find pivot position, "pivot"
    ...
    # arrange list on either side of pivot
    ...
    # recur on each part of list. 
    q_sort(alist, low_index, pivot-1)
    q_sort(alist, pivot+1, high_index)
```

Is that enough of an outline to get you moving?

If not, try a browser search on "Python quicksort", and you'll find a lot of help, more thorough than we can cover here.

Comment: I think I may be a bit out of my depth, probably naive of me to think that I could write my own quick sort. Thank-you nonetheless

Comment: Okay, then ... start with a simpler sort, then a simpler recursive sort (such as a recursive version of the bubble sort), and then try an inherently recursive sort, such as merge sort.  There's nothing wrong with writing your own version; at this point, you just need to do a little more work to ensure you're following the given algorithm.  Also, try inserting some simple `print` statements to track the data and flow.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.